# ActiveRecord query methods on namespaced models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a common set of models extracted into a gem with namespaced models as such:

```
module Gemifive
  class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
  end

  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :activities
  end
end
```

That's in the gem "gemifive". So far, so good.

In an app where I use this gem's models, I can do the following: `Gemifive::Activity.where(user_id: user.id)`. This works fine because that table has a `user_id` column:

```
SELECT "gemifive_activities".* FROM "gemifive_activities" WHERE "gemifive_activities"."user_id" = 18`
```

However, the following **does not** work work: `Gemifive::Activity.where(user: user)`. This generates the following SQL, which is invalid:

```
SELECT "gemifive_activities".* FROM "gemifive_activities" WHERE "gemifive_activities"."user" = 18
```

I can access `Gemifive::Activity.first.user` just fine, so I know the `belongs_to` association is working. Why can't I use this ActiveRecord convention?

Comment: What code are you using set the value of `user` in the case that fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Gemifive::Activity.where(user: user)
```

This is invalid ARel, plain and simple. It has nothing to do with your models being namespaced. In the above code, ARel is using the key of the Hash as the column name, and it will be used verbatim. What you *can* do is

```
Gemifive::Activity.where(user_id: user)
```

Comment: You know what, you're right. I'm not sure why I expected this to work and I am possibly losing my mind. I must been confused by the fact that things like `Order.create(user: some_user)` works in that AR does some magic to convert the `user` key to `user_id` in the INSERT statement.